# How do I create an Alembic geometry Cache or animation from a series of meshes

Tags: animation, export, unreal-engine, cache, alembic

I have a series of meshes that I would like to export to unreal and have them read as a geometry cache or animation. I have about 60 meshes and I would like each mesh to be a single frame of an animation. Basically I want to create a 3D mesh flipbook asset for vfx.

The way I did this before was using 3ds max and unreals vertex animation tools script. https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/Animation/Tools/VertexAnimationTool

Is there a way I can do this with Alembic or any other way from blender.

I'm really stuck here so any help you guys can provide would be greatly appreciated.